# force php to overwrite a table even if it has duplicate entry

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have already uploaded the .sql file to my server since it is 6GB. When I try to import it to the database it gives me a duplicate entry error 1062 primary table. Is it possible to force the file to overwrite the existing table? I have also tried deleting the entire table then importing which it does until it gets to 4.2GB then it gives me the error of a duplicate entry. These are emails that I am trying to import the emails back into the accounts but this error is preventing me from doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

I also made sure that I can upload from a directory on the webserver.
Select from the web server upload directory ./upload/:

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key cannot have duplicate entries. What you could do is remote the PRIMARY index in your table's structure, then do the import, fix the duplicate entries and create the PRIMARY index on the same column(s).